# best way stream images to a remote server?

Tags: c#, php, ffmpeg, flv

I want to stream the user screen (of the computer using C# app) to a remote server (PHP) through an FLV player or any other way.

I take a screenshot each 1 seconds, send it as base64 data to the remte server, then save it as X.jpg on the remote server, where X is an incrementing number.

Once I reach 100 images, I use the command below in order to convert the images into a video :

```
exec('ffmpeg -y -r 2 -f image2 -i img%d.jpg -r 20 temp.flv 2>&1 >/dev/null', $output, $exit_status);
```

Once the video is created, I display it to the user and delete all files, then repeat the process again, and again in order to keep streaming.

This way doesn't really work as expected and it has a lot of drawbacks.

Is there any alternative way I can broadcast the taken screenshots  to the remote client in his browser without having to convert the images to a video and play it and keep on repeating this process ??

Comment: this sounds suspicious!

Comment: So far your question is off-topic: you are either searching for tools OR you need to provide way more details than "doesn't really work as expected".

Answer (score 0):

Google "live screencasting software", you'll save time.

As for your current approach:

1. Encode the image as a JPG *before* sending it over the network, you'll likely save quite a bit of bandwidth.
2. Don't base64 encode anything unless you really need it to be 7-bit safe. [eg. email] Base64 encoded data is generally 1.33 times the size of the input.